# Localhost website/virtualhost forces www prefix

Tags: apache, localhost

so first some information. I have a live JOOMLA website(working fine) which I copied(httpdocs file with FTP and exported/imported database) to my localhost server and created a virtual host for it. So far working with no problems.

Now the problem is, when I try to visit the page, either by clicking in Wampserver homepage or manually type the url in the address bar, it automatically adds www. infront. Comes out like this *www.joomla/* instead of *joomla/* so I can't access the page. But when I go to the administration page it works fine *joomla/administrator*. But it says not secure if that means anything

Now I've tried editing the .htaccess file with the rewrite function but it didn't help. I am completely lost by now. Might it be some settings in the files from the live site?

Comment: This adding of `www.` comes from somewhere - either `.htaccess` (it's a hidden file, maybe you copied it too?) or apache `conf` files. You must find where it's added.

Comment: Yes I also copied .htaccess, I tried deleting it or changing some rewrite settings but nothing seemed to help. I think I found out where the problem is. I did a fresh install and copied files manually, and there are 2 components of joomla com_sef and com_redirect that are doing this, I already posted on the joomla forum